# Change Bootstrap 4 carousel direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the direction of the carousel from left to right to **top to bottom**. All I've found are answers for Bootstrap 3 and they're not working. How can I do this in Bootstrap 4?

Here's the carousel code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the default directions, Just add below styles in your css file and make sure your css file load after your bootstrap :

```
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 .carousel-item-next,
 .active.carousel-item-right {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }
 .carousel-item-prev,
 .active.carousel-item-left {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, +100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, +100, 0);
 }
```

I made an example for u :

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/L6cm19hL/2/

Comment: Thanks alot!! Been searching for it a while

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-item-next,
.active.carousel-item-right {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.carousel-item-prev,
.active.carousel-item-left {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.carousel-control-prev {
    top: 0;
    bottom: unset;
}

.carousel-control-next {
    top: unset;
    bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/* Change the direction of the transition. Left To Right in bootstrap4 by css Only*/

Just put this code in the RTL.css file and it will reverse the direction **"it will override bootstrap css code"**

```
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
.active.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right) {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .active.carousel-item-right, .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left) {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
        }
   }
```